# How to separate Nuxt JSON payload from HTML in SSR (universal) mode?

Tags: nuxt.js, server-side-rendering, payload

How to separate Nuxt JSON payload from HTML in SSR (universal mode)?

I want to remove this piece of code (see screenshot) from my HTML output and place it to a separate file.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is a really bad idea. window.**NUXT** object contains data required to hydration process.

**You might ask what is the hydration process?**
It is process during which Vue takes SSR HTML Output and transform it to dynamic DOM so it becomes reactive. You could read more about it there: https://ssr.vuejs.org/guide/hydration.html

What's interesting, you could probably limit length of this object by using Lazy Hydration. Check this repo: https://github.com/maoberlehner/vue-lazy-hydration

Comment: I don't want to remove it completely, I just want to move it to a separate file.